# Convert tuple to function parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

```
template<typename... Args>
class SomeClass
{
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<Args...>; // (ie: <bool,int,bool>)   
    tuple_type mytuple;
};

template<typename T, typename C, typename... I> // T is SomeClass
class SomeOtherClass
{       

      void fn(void(C::*f)(bool,int,bool)); // I want this
      // based on the T::tuple_type but I'm not sure how. 

};
```

I could simply use tuple_element 3 times if i knew the tuple has 3 elements only, but I don't know that.

Comment: Is there a reason why do you want to have `(bool, int, bool)` instead of `(typename T::tuple_type&)`?

Comment: I'm using a tuple to store arguments for a callback. You can pass a [](bool a,  int b, bool c) lambda (and the parameters have names which is good), rather than a [](tuple) which is more complex due to the use of get<> or having to store them in local variables to give them a meaningful names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a generic type trait:

```
template <class C, class F>
struct mem_ptr;

template <class C, class F>
using mem_ptr_t = typename mem_ptr<C, F>::type;
```

And specialize it for `tuple`:

```
template <class C, class... Args>
struct mem_ptr<C, std::tuple<Args...>> {
    using type = void (C::*)(Args...);
};
```

And then use it:

```
void fun(mem_ptr_t<C, typename T::tuple_type> f);
```

This assumes you want `void` as the return type.

---

Could generalize this to splitting up the `mem_ptr` part from the tuple to func part:

```
template <class C, class F>
struct mem_ptr {
    using type = F C::*;
};

template <class C, class F>
using mem_ptr_t = typename mem_ptr<C, F>::type;

template <class R, class T>
struct tuple_to_func;

template <class R, class... Args>
struct tuple_to_func<R, std::tuple<Args...>> {
    using type = R(Args...);
};

template <class R, class T>
using tuple_to_func_t = typename tuple_to_func<R, T>::type;
```

In which case you'd want:

```
void fun(mem_ptr_t<C,
    tuple_to_func_t<void, typename T::tuple_type>
> f);
```